# Error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'password'

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am new at C#
I create a class for SQL command and function to use at form (login)
here is the class (login):-

```
            public void UPDATE(int id_, string nameA, string nameL,  string TEL, string TYPEROLE, string PASSWORD)
            {
                var DAL = new SQlcls.DataAccessLayer();
                var PRM = new SqlParameter[6];

                PRM[0] = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
                PRM[0].Value = id_;
                PRM[1] = new SqlParameter("@nameA", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                PRM[1].Value = nameA;
                PRM[2] = new SqlParameter("@nameL", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                PRM[2].Value = nameL;
                PRM[3] = new SqlParameter("@TEL", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                PRM[3].Value = TEL;
                PRM[4] = new SqlParameter("@TYPEROLE", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                PRM[4].Value = TYPEROLE;
                PRM[5] = new SqlParameter("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                PRM[5].Value = PASSWORD;
                DAL.ExeuteCmd_txt("UPDATE [dbo].[USERS]  SET  =[id]=@ID,[nameA]=@nameA ,[nameL]=@nameL ,[TEL]=@TEL,[TYPEROLE]=@TYPEROLE ,[PASSWORD]=@PASSWORD WHERE ID=@ID", PRM);
            }
```

and this the code in form (users) which I will save the records to the database :-

```
        private void SAVEEDITE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                try
            {

                LOGIN LOGN = new LOGIN();
                LOGN.UPDATE( Convert.ToInt32(TXT_ID.Text),
                        TXT_NAMEL.Text,
                        TXT_TEL.Text,
                        TXT_TYPEROLE.Text,
                        TXT_PASSWORD.Text);

                MessageBox.Show("تم التعديل بنجاح", "تأكيد", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                save.Visible = false;
                ADD.Visible = true;
                Edit.Visible = true;
                DELETE.Visible = true;
                UNDO.Visible = false;
                SAVEEDITE.Visible = false;
                TXT_ID.Enabled = true;
                TXT_ID.ReadOnly = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

I get the error :CS7036  C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter of 'password'

Comment: At whichever line this error occurs, you call a method but do not pass the correct number of parameters or parameters in the wrong order. Look at the documentation/signature of the method you try to call that causes the error and pay attention to (a) the number of parameters the method requires, (b) the order of the parameters, and (c) the type of the parameters.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` function takes 6 arguments, but it looks like you are only passing 5 in the call.

Comment: that is right .. thanks for the help .. i missed 1 argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying the compiler looked for a value for the password parameter but could not find it.

Looking at your code, that is a parameter of the `UPDATE` method.

In your call to the `UPDATE` method, you are indeed supplying a password.  So why the error?  Well, we have to ensure the arguments we are passing match up with the parameters in the method signature.  In this case, you are passing the password as the fifth parameter, which maps to `TYPEROLE`.  So the password is being assigned to `TYPEROLE`, and there is no value being assigned to the password parameter, hence the error.

Side note: You are using a seemingly random mix of upper and lower case for your parameter names.  I'd recommend consistent casing in order to improve code maintainability.  A commonly accepted standard for parameter names is [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).  Using this scheme, `TYPEROLE` becomes `typeRole`, for example.